# dynamic SQL string wont work with double quotes

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sql-injection

I made a dynamic SQL string with js that looks at the records only a few days in the past.

```
var dateSearch = new Date();
dateSearch.setDate(dateSearch.getDate() - 3);
var dateSearchInput = dateSearch.toISOString();

...q=SELECT * FROM \"daily log\" WHERE date >= threeMonthInput"];
```

The SQL query below works with the result of dateSearch but not with it as a variable like above, this works for example:

```
...q=SELECT * FROM \"daily log\" WHERE date >= \'2018-05-06T05:17:47.270Z\'"];
```

I have tried adding \' on each side of the variable, still nothing.

Any insight to get this working as a variable. Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the table ? "daily log" is that a valid table name? also please post the error message. Which is the database ?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Yep, daily log is the table and the request functions normally when hard-coding the date in manually. 

i console log the result and it just says undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add a variable as a string in the URL. I needed to seporate the string, add the variable and finish the string.

Solution is:

```
...q=SELECT * FROM \"daily log\" WHERE date >= '" + threeMonthInput + "\'"];
```